# Unable to install Grafana via Helm

Tags: grafana, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to install Grafana via helm and have added both the bitnami and stable repo.

from bitnami

```
helm install bitnami/grafana grafana --set persistence.enabled=true --set persistence.accessModes={ReadWriteOnce} --set persistence.size=8Gi --namespace monitoring
```

stable

```
grafana $ helm install stable/grafana grafana --set persistence.enabled=true --set persistence.accessModes={ReadWriteOnce} --set persistence.size=8Gi --namespace monitoring
```

However, I get the following error:

> helm install stable/grafana grafana --set persistence.enabled=true
>   --set persistence.accessModes={ReadWriteOnce} --set persistence.size=8Gi --namespace monitoring Error: failed to download
>   "grafana" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)

I have tried `helm repo update` but it doesn't help.

I will appreciate some guidance on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax is  **helm install [NAME] [CHART] [flags]**
helm install grafana stable/grafana xxxxx should work 
You just put the chart name in the wrong position

Answer (score 0):

Need to search grafana in hub using Helm

helm search hub grafana

helm repo add grafana https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts

helm repo update

helm install my-release grafana/grafana

And for particular namespace:
helm install my-release grafana/grafana -n test-namespace

Answer (score 0):

You can below command:
helm install my-grafana-board grafana/grafana

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).